# finding the index of the first letter of a sub string in the main string

Tags: python

I am trying to find the index of the first letter of a sub string within the main string. The function acts exactly like the find method of python. I have created a find_chr function that gives me the index of a character in a string and I am using the find_chr to get the index of the substring.

```
def find_str(s,x):
    i=0
    if x in s:
        return find_chr(s,x[i])
    else:
        return -1
```

My problem is that when I am using the string "IS GOING GOING" and substring as "ING", I am getting the index of the first "I", when I am expecting the index of the "I" of "ING". I will appreciate any input about changing the function to get the right index of the first letter of the substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `find_str` you call `find_chr(s,x[i])`.  This is calling `find_chr` with only `x[i]` (the ith part of the substring).

This should fix your problem

```
def find_chr(s,char):
    i=0
    step = len(char)
    for j in range(len(s)+1):
        ch = s[j:j+step]
        if ch==char:
            return (i)
            break
        i+=1
    return -1

def find_str(s,x):
    i=0
    if x in s:
        return find_chr(s,x)
    else:
        return -1
```

Comment: No, it will not. find_chr function takes a string and a character. if I pass two strings as argument, it will not work.

Comment: @cobra I changed your program - it will take two strings (and python doesn't consider strings and characters differently).

Besides, if you only pass it a single character then it will only return the first instance of that character, not the one you actually want.

Comment: I ran the program with your modified version and I am not getting the right index. It is returning the index as -1 for 'ING", when the index should be 5.

Comment: @cobra Are you sure you're running exactly what I entered? I get the correct index of 5 when I run this http://puu.sh/6WlXm.png

Comment: Sorry, I didn't change the find_chr function like you have done. That is why, I was not getting the right answer. I ran your code and it gave the right answer. Thanks a lot for your input and patience.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't looping through the characters, you only check for `i == 0` (i.e. the first character in `s`). You need to apply a "window" to the string, checking `len(s)` characters in a row:

```
def find_str(s, x):
    if x in s: # is x present?
        for i in range(len(s)): # work through string indices
            if s[i:i+len(x)] == x: # does x start at current index?
                return i
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the use of the index function in strings. You will then happily replace all of that code with about 1 line.

Supplying the answer because of the following comments. Seriously though, if one is going to learn python, it is a good exercise to be aware of the methods available for an object.

```
>>> 'is going going'.index('ing')
5
```

or more generally

```
>>> fullstring.index(substring)
```

This should be marked as the correct answer because it is the simplest and most obviously correct. The complexity of the algorithms offered is way too high for this problem.

If the substring is not in the fullstring, a ValueError exception will be raised. So if you need a function, then it should return the index from a try or -1 (or None) from the except blocks.

Comment: Please consider elaborating more on why this solves OP's issue and how.

Comment: Right - show that one line of code. Otherwise, anyone who stumbles upon this answer in the future has to also *look up the use of the index function in strings.*

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
def find_str(s, x):
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i:i + len(x)] == x:
            return i
        else:
            i += 1
print find_str('IS GOING GOING', 'ING')
```